# How to find decimal of variables

Tags: php

I have one problem in my project.

```
$value="Rs.1,195";
echo getfloat($value);
```

I need out is only

> 1195

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $string = "Rs.1,195";
 print preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$string);
```

> **Output** = 1195

Comment: This will blow up on negative numbers and numbers that contain a decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for floatval()

Answer (score 0):

```
$value="Rs.1,195";
$int = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```